# Sprite Kit shooting projectiles at target

Tags: sprite-kit

I wanted to make my turret Sprite shoot at the monster. i have already got the turret to turn to the monster and follow it until its out of range, now i just need to make the shooting occur.

what is the best way to shoot a projectile from the turret to the monster?

i have already done this part:

```
-(void)shoot
{
     SKSpriteNode *bullet = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"CannonMissile-hd.png"]; ... i don't know what to do next

}
```

also, i need it to shoot at intervals of x seconds,

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
-(void)shoot
{
    SKSpriteNode *turretNode;//I assume you have this node already in the scene . Dont use this line
    SKSpriteNode *enemy;//I assume you have this node already in the scene . Dont use this line
    SKSpriteNode *bullet = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"CannonMissile-hd.png"];
    bullet.zPosition = turretNode.zPosition -1;//if you want your bullet not to spawn on top of your turret
    [turretNode addChild:bullet];
    //you need to set the physics body of the bullet so you can detect contacts
    SKAction *move = [SKAction moveTo:enemy.position duration:0.5];//if u have multiple enemies then you have to deceide which one to hit
    [bullet runAction:move completion:^{
        [bullet removeFromParent];//removes the bullet when it reaches target
        //you can add more code here or in the didBeginContact method
    }];
    //repeat the process
    [self performSelector:@selector(shoot) withObject:nil afterDelay:5];//replace 5 with ur x seconds
    //that's it
}
```